# Save multiple tables in same .tex-file using xtable

Tags: r, latex, xtable

Lets say I have six matrices of size 50*5 stored in an array, e.g.,

```
my.array<-array(1:1500, dim=c(50,5,6))
```

and want to save these as multiple tables in the same .tex-file. i.e., I want the final result to be a tex-file with six separate latex tables without having to manually having to save each matrix and then copy them into a single .tex-document. What is the best way to do this, preferably using xtable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :
`append=TRUE` in the argument list of the function `print.xtable`

See: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xtable/versions/1.8-4/topics/print.xtable